# How to fix the stuck after the command, 'bash flash.sh'

Tags: bash, google-coral

I was trying to flash the mendel-enterprise-chef-13 to the Coral EdgeTPU Development Board but got stuck after the command, "bash flash.sh."

The host computer is the MacBook Pro (2018) with macOS Mojave ver. 10 and connected with the Coral EdgeTPU Dev Board.

I have followed the instructions on the Coral Document listed at https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/. 
The process went smooth up to without the problem untill the step 8 and 12.

1. mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
2. sudo mv ~/Downloads/platform-tools/fastboot ~/.local/bin/
3. pip3 install --user mendel-development-tool
4. and then install the CP210x USB to UART Bridge Virtual COM Port (VCP) driver for Mac.
5. screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200
6. fastboot 0
7. fastboot devices
8. 1b0741d6f0609912        fastboot # I did not get this message
9. cd ~/Downloads
10. curl -O https://dl.google.com/coral/mendel/enterprise/mendel-enterprise-chef-13.zip
11. unzip mendel-enterprise-chef-13.zip \
    && cd mendel-enterprise-chef-13
12. bash flash.sh # Got stuck here.

I want to know how to fix the issues of flashing the mendel image.

Comment: Depending on the image size and your computer/device it could take a long time to flash. Have you given it enough time?

Comment: yes, I did. I waited one hour but nothing showed on the screen. One thing puzzles me is that nothing showed after the command, "fastboot devices." It supposed to show the output like "1b0741d6f0609912        fastboot."

Comment: The script needs a SERIAL variable in order to connect with a device. You could make use of echo to see whether or not every variable is set and where the script eventually hangs. Some commands endlessly wait if not every parameter is set (i.e. `grep` without a file). Also, make sure fastboot works properly. You will have to do some debugging to get this working. Good luck!

Comment: I found that the problem is with the cable. I changed the cable to USB-A/USB-C and it worked magically.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a problem with the USB-A USB-C cable, or the usb port on your host machine, have you tried a different port?

Comment: OP found the solution to their issue; it was in fact a cable issue. This post doesn't attempt to answer the question and really should be posted as a comment. That's the proper way to ask for clarification on questions.

Comment: Ahh, I see, apologies